# Webrtc Android to Android?

Tags: android, webrtc, videochat

Im a bit confused, Ive only seen examples from android to pc or vice versa. I need to make an android app that connects from two phones(android) for video chat. I was wondering, I know it might be a silly question, but can you do that with webrtc? Do you know any good tutorials that explains it or something similar? Or can you recommend any good books that treats the subject?

Does my project need to be in a Linux enviroment machine?

Edited: Okay Ive implemented it on the web, it works for pc browsers. But I cannot put it in a Web View since Android´s native browser does not allow access to native camera. So how can I put the html and javascript code inside the android app without using its browser?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The connection logic is the same as android to pc...it is utilizing the same API.

Comment: Nice, that is clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is it possible to do that, but also need a server, to exchange ICE or STUN candidates, only WebRTC can't do that. I developed such a program, only resource that I had, it was source codes and official link [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android). It's API change very often, so I don't think that there will be a book about that, practically it is possible to use it without any books, there is a WebRTCDemo project that is enough.

> Does my project need to be in a Linux enviroment machine?

Not mandatory, but it is very recommended to use a Linux environment

**Update: the link is not working anymore**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In regards to that,  you used a STUN server right?

Comment: Yes, if use only TURN, the load on servers will be very high, if use only STUN, there can be cases, when connection can not be establish due to symmetric NAT or other network issues, so for stability both are needed.

Comment: @mes To get better intuition you can follow this documentation:
https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC, It is confirmed that Signaling is not part of WebRTC, but you either use `NATs.io` or `firebase` to share SDP&ICECandidates between peers. "libjingle" is the best source for peer-to-peer communication of audio/video over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with WebRTC. It's already done, and was already done at the time of this question.

The AppRTCDemo program from [here](http://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) is an Android WebRTC client. Using Google's server [infrastructure](https://apprtc.appspot.com/), you can connect any two WebRTC peers, including two Android peers. As far as I know, there is not a binary Android implementation available, but you can download the source code (it's massive, ~15GB) and build this yourself, with no actual programming required.

If you want to implement your own server component, you can start from the [apprtc source code](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc).